# DropDownList event not firing with AutoPostBack set to true

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have DropDownList in my webpage and I would like to fill TextBoxes every time when user change selected value in DropDownList.

My problem is that this event is not firing when I change this value. Interesting thing is, that this event is fired only when I change value AND press button, which create new request.

I tried to change AutoPostBack value to true, tried to change ViewStateMode and i tried fire this function on textChanged event. 
I also added condition !isPostBack before databinding function.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    LoadDatabaseContent();
}
```

Here is event function.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44333/Backend2.aspx?update=true&id=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    int count;  
    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            string tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

            sb.Append(tempString);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0);
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());

    //createTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();

    resStream.Dispose();
    response.Dispose();
}
```

ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Backend.aspx.cs" Inherits="APIS.Backend" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="buttonGeneratePdf" runat="server" OnClick="buttonGeneratePdf_Click" Text="Generate PDF" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="buttonGenerateQrCode" runat="server" OnClick="buttonGenerateQrCode_Click" Text="Generate QR" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="16px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
OnTextChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I have two "backends" that communicate between each other. First create REST requests and second accept this request and based on query string get desired value from database or in this case, generate QR code.

When I press button it create request. For example:

```
protected void buttonGenerateQrCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44333/Backend2.aspx?generateqrcode=true&id=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        int count;
        do
        {
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                string tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());

        //createTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();

        resStream.Dispose();
        response.Dispose();
    }
```

And in backend which communicate with database is this request accepted:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string generateQrCode = Request.QueryString["generateqrcode"];
        if (generateQrCode != null && generateQrCode == "true") GenerateQrCode();
    }
```

Which calls function:

```
private void GenerateQrCode()
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        QRCodeGenerator qr = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData data = qr.CreateQrCode(id, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode code = new QRCode(data);
        Bitmap QRbmp = code.GetGraphic(5);
        QRbmp.Save("pathtofile..\\QRcode.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: Can you view source and confirm that there is javascript being generated for the dropdown list's HTML element?  Are you seeing any JS errors in the console when you select a new value in the dropdownlist?

Comment: Also you mentioned "pressing a button" but I don't see one in this form.

Comment: No, I can't see any javascript, or at least I dont know, how could I see it. This is my first web app so Im pretty new to this.

Comment: In most web browsers, when you view the page you should be able to right-click and choose "View Source".  In chrome you can press F12 to open the dev tools window, which will give you a Javascript console.

Comment: Yes, now I can see it. It throws this exception: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at __doPostBack (Backend:64)
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: And that is: 
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}

Exception is in eventTarget on line: theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

Comment: What browser are you using,  does this happen in one particular browser or all browsers?

Comment: Im using Google Chrome. I tried it on Edge but result was same.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Javascript is failing to execute because the elements `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` do not exist on your form.  On the generated HTML, the form should contain the following hidden elements:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
```

You should try to confirm if these elements are being generated, and if not try to track down why they're not there.  You may need to use an `<asp:Form>` tag rather than `<form runat="server">` but that's really just a guess on my part at this point.